# Windows 10 Bluetooth device won't connect after windows reset

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, system-restore

So, after two years with a single windows installation it began to give me some troubles, so I thought it might be time to reset is back clean install. On this installation I had my Sony WH-1000MX2 working perfectly.

After the wipe and installing all my software again, I thought OK, just the headphones and i'm done. That's where the problems begin.

I set the headset in pairing mode, go though the standard Bluetooth paring. It finds it, connects to it. Says connected for like 5 seconds and go's in to "Paired" when manually connecting it will just say "That didn't work. Make sure your Bluetooth device is still discoverable, then try again".

I have removed it from the list, and turning on/off Bluetooth it sometimes show back up again, so I used registry editor to remove the Device from 
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`

I have uninstalled the Bluetooth module from Device management, I have tried to uninstall the driver from device manager. I can't seem to find anything strange in the Windows event log.

After about 2 days of trying, no success.

I know it might be strange, but it feels like the windows reset kept the connection to the headphones and the old security code used to connect to it some where, but I can't seem to make windows forget it. When i connect an different Bluetooth dongle, it works almost instantly, so am i missing some registry entry somewhere to make it work with the internal module again?

Answer (score 16):

had a similar issue to this, finally managed to sort it out.

My symptoms:

- Previously working bluetooth speaker (UE BOOM 2 in my case) stops connecting
- Windows 10 'Bluetooth and other devices' menu shows the device as Paired
- Pressing connect makes it attempt to connect but fails then it goes back to Paired
- Remove device hides the device from the menu, but as soon as you turn bluetooth on and off, or restart the computer, the device comes back
- You pull your hair out.

Solution that worked for me after much, much unsuccessful internet trawling and one system restore:

- Download this 7 year old command line bluetooth toolset: http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/
- Install it, make sure you enable the option to "Add Bluetooth Command Line Tools directory to path"
- Open Powershell
- Put your device that isn't working properly into pairing mode

WARNING: THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WILL UNPAIR ALL BLUETOOTH DEVICES

- type in "btpair -u"
- Boom, all of a sudden Windows asks me if I want to allow pairing to my device that isn't working
- Hit yes, successfully connected again
- Cry tears of joy

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea why this solution worked for me when so many other solutions I've tried have not worked -- and believe me, I've tried quite a few other solutions.  Thanks so much for sharing this!

Comment: Same here in 2020. Thank you!

Comment: You had me hopeful, but sadly it didn't work for me. Bluetooth was working just fine. Then today I noticed it was doing the whole "muting silence" but which was making ambient noises get muted... so I unpaired and tried to repair and off to the rodeo.... sadly I'm stuck at this paired but won't connect stage now.

Comment: I could not test this without admin rights. Can anyone tell whether this still helps in 2024?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same annoying problem. After many months I have stumbled across this post, and it finally worked. Thank God!

> Thankfully I managed to find a solution a while ago. For some reason, Windows is assuming your Bluetooth device has a screen. To fix it you need to tell it that it doesn't.
>
> - Go to **Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers** (the old control panel).
> - You should see your device listed somewhere. The next part is very inconsistent.
> - Double click your device and wait; for some reason it doesn't appear right away. Just continue using your computer as normal. Eventually (maybe) you should get a popup that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrOEh.png). Select "headset type", then tick "My hands-free device X does not have a display" and apply. That should solve it!
> - If the popup doesn't show, try double clicking it a few times and wait again. If that doesn't work, try right clicking and selecting "Control" a few times and continue using your computer.
>
> Just to note, the popup is very inconsistent. Sometimes it will show, sometimes not. Additionally, you may find that the popup will appear and then close shortly after. If this happens, you just need to be fast at clicking the correct tick box and apply.
>
> Hope this helps! Let me know if you fix it.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/6jn2je/windows_10_wont_connect_to_bluetooth_speakers/doommg0

Comment: On my Lenovo W530 that worked only AFTER I updated drivers from June 2015 to September 2015; only after that I could get the mentioned pop-up window. But there I had to switch "My device does not have display", click "Apply"; then "My device can display information", click "Apply"; only after that it worked!

Comment: This did not fix it, but it was good to check the services that the phone runs. I unchecked all of them since I do not pair the phone to make phone calls or have sound on the laptop, I only do it for the internet. Again, that did not fix it, but this other way to change the settings of the phone is still good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Alright this fixed the problem for me, I opened device manager and hit View -> Show Hidden Devices. This made a series of hidden bluetooth devices visible, and after uninstalling all of those drivers, I reconnected my speaker and it worked perfectly.

Comment: already tried that, did not work. But thanks for the answer

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.
Device Manager > View - Show Hidden Devices > Uninstall all Blutetooth from bottom to top.

Comment: Yes, I had to **remove every single item under Bluetooth**. I think my problem stemmed from using multiple USB bluetooth dongles. And I was only getting **connect failed** and **remove failed** trying to use my headphones. This, plus reboot, _finally_ cleared and reset everything.

Comment: This did not fix it, but the hint at the hidden devices is still helpful, I was not aware of it although I opened the device manager for many times in my Windows life.

Comment: This did not fix it, but the hint at the hidden devices is still helpful, I was not aware of it although I opened the device manager for many times in my Windows life.